# How to create two APFS containers with same size?

Tags: apfs, diskutil

I have a virtual disk of 1 GB, on which I want to create two volumes of 400 MB. With

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 2 GPT APFS VOLUME1 400M APFS VOLUME2 400M
```

it created one APFS container of 400 MB and another one of 600 MB.

How can I create two containers of 400 MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a third triplet which instructs `diskutil` where to put the remaining unused free space. For example, to place the free space after the second APFS container of 400 MB, the command would be the following.

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 3 GPT APFS VOLUME1 400M APFS VOLUME2 400M free none R
```

The word `free` means free space. Since free space cannot have a name, the word none is just used as a placeholder. The letter `R` means remainder. In other words, the remaining space after creating all other partitions is left unused.

Below is an excerpt from `man diskutil` which explains further. The version of macOS is Ventura 13.3.1 (a).

> The last partition is usually automatically lengthened to the
> end of the partition map (disk).  You can specify an exact
> size for your last partition by specifying it as the
> penultimate triplet and specifying an additional (last)
> triplet as **Free Space**.  Or you can use the **R** (remainder) size
> specifier for one of your middle partitions while specifying
> an exact size for your last partition.

Below is the output from `diskutil list`.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 GB     disk0
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         400.0 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         400.0 MB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         200.0 MB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +400.0 MB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s1
   1:                APFS Volume VOLUME1                 24.6 KB    disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +400.0 MB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume VOLUME2                 24.6 KB    disk2s1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I used this workaround.

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 3 GPT APFS VOLUME1 400M APFS VOLUME2 400M APFS VOLUME3 0b
```

It create 3 APFS containers, 2 of 400 MB, and with the rest of space going to the APFS container with the volume labeled `VOLUME3`.

Comment: Rather than create the `VOLUME3`, you could have just left free space by using the command `partitionDisk /dev/disk0 3 GPT APFS VOLUME1 400M APFS VOLUME2 400M free none R`. The word `free` means free space. Since free space cannot have a name, the word `none` is just used as a placeholder. The letter`R` means remainder. In other words, the remaining space after creating all other partitions is left unused.

Comment: Add as answer, please So I can vote and close question